# Can't update Developer Story open source project info

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story

I was just updating [my Developer Story](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/99692) (currently set private, so the link is only for the sake of SE developers) content, and I found that I could not edit one of my GitHub open source project entries ([ShinySDR](https://github.com/kpreid/shinysdr)).

Specifically, whenever I click the Save button, it *clears* the "Link to the repository" (which already had a good, and uneditable, value) and displays a required-field error (and is still uneditable, so I cannot save).

[image]

I did not experience this error when editing other GitHub entries. It might have something to do with it having been imported from a previous iteration of Stack Overflow Careers-or-Jobs-or-whatever.

I expect that I could delete and recreate the entry as a workaround. I'm leaving it be for now for the sake of reproducing the bug.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this! Looking into it now.

Answer (score 1):

We recently shipped a feature that automatically syncs an open source story item with GitHub if:

1. the story item has a valid GitHub project url
2. you have provided a valid GitHub username on your developer story and have contribution activity for that project under this username, specially commits

We update the repository statistics (last commit date, number of total commits, additions, subtractions) if you have pushed to the repository in the last 7 days. We use [GitHub's Events API](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/) and check for "PushEvent"s for repository urls that match items on your developer story.

Since we use the url of the user story item to sync the repository statistics, we make the url field uneditable. However, there was a bug that was overriding the Url with null values when editing an item that has been synced with GitHub. This should now be fixed on production!

Thanks very much for reporting this :).